# Is there any way to clean the quotation "" in my column of my dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

Here is my sample of dataset:

```
school  sex   age  address
"GP    ""F""   18   ""U""
"GP    ""F""   19   ""U""
"GP    ""M""   15   ""R""
```

here are my sample of code

```
student_data$school = gsub('"', '', student_data$school)
student_data$sex = gsub('"', '', student_data$sex)
student_data$address = gsub('"', '', student_data$address)
```

it has 33 attribute actually so it is quite dumb to do it line by line. Is there anyway to remove the quotation marks in my column of my dataset in r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(student_data)){
student_data[,i]= gsub('"', '', student_data[,i])
}
```

Let me know if it worked

Comment: This converts the age column to character.  Use `c(1:2, 4)` instead of `1:ncol(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~gsub('"', "", .)))
```

```
   school sex age address
1:     GP   F  18       U
2:     GP   F  19       U
3:     GP   M  15       R
```

```
dat = fread('school  sex   age  address
"GP    ""F""   18   ""U""
"GP    ""F""   19   ""U""
"GP    ""M""   15   ""R""')
```

Comment: `everything()` should be `where(is.character)`